# Extract a particular link present in each of the considered web pages

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble extracting a particular link from each of the web pages I'm considering.

In particular, considering for example the following websites:

- https://lefooding.com/en/restaurants/ezkia
- https://lefooding.com/en/restaurants/tekes

I would like to know if there is a unique way to extract the field WEBSITE (above the map) shown in the table on the left of the page.
For the reported cases, I would like to extract the links:

- https://www.ezkia-restaurant.fr/
- https://www.tekesrestaurant.com/

There are no unique tags to refer to and this makes extraction difficult.
I've thought of a solution using the selector, but it doesn't seem to work. For the first link I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://lefooding.com/en/restaurants/ezkia"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find("div", {"class": "e-rowContent"})
print(data)
```

but there is no trace of the link I need here. Does anyone know of a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
    "https://lefooding.com/en/restaurants/ezkia",
    "https://lefooding.com/en/restaurants/tekes",
]

with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        soup = [
            link.strip() for link 
            in BeautifulSoup(
                s.get(url).text, "lxml"
            ).select(".pageGuide__infos a")[-1]
        ]
        print(soup)
```

Output:

```
['https://www.ezkia-restaurant.fr']
['https://www.tekesrestaurant.com/']
```